# Does the AppleTV support multiple Apple ID accounts?

Tags: icloud, appletv, apple-id

I'm considering buying the new AppleTV, but I'm wondering if it works in the way that I want it to work. What I would like is that my wife can take pictures on her iPhone and have them sync via iCloud to the AppleTV, but I want all iTunes purchases like videos to be on my account.

Will this work on the new AppleTV or is it limited to a single iCloud account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a single apple id in iTunes homesharing on all devices that you want on your appleTV

#### **BUT**

This does not mean that you can't buy anything anymore with your personal apple ID everything you buy will still be placed in your library and will be shared on the 'family' apple ID account

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4352

Comment: So, this would mean to support multiple Apple ID's I would need multiple machines running iTunes. Is this a correct assumption?